# Converting Right and Instr into vb.net Substring

Tags: vb.net, vba, substring

I wrote a code in VBA and I'm trying to transfer it to Vb.Net but I'm not sure of my job.

VBA code (adapted to vb.net):

```
Dim stringDate$ = "something happens: 03/12/2014 11:00"
    Dim C$ = Trim(Strings.Right(stringDate, Len(stringDate) - InStr(1, stringDate, ":", vbTextCompare)))
```

Vb.Net code:

```
Dim C$ = stringDate.substring(stringDate.length - stringDate.indexof(":"), stringDate.length - (stringDate.length -stringDate.indexof(":"))).trim()
```

But a longer code doesn't seem like an improvement. Isn't it?

What is the right way?

Comment: If you are comfortable with the legacy VB functions like `Len` and `Instr` then use them.  Personally, I dislike them because so many of them involve boxing arguments to and from Object with no other benefit.  "Longer code" is less meaningful than the boxing.

Comment: stringDate.Substring(stringDate.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim() is shorter and does not bomb.

Comment: When doing.Net development I prefer the methods off of string for a couple of reasons.  For one, the VB versions are not instance methods so they have to check if the string passed in is null.  This can be a lot of unnecessary checks if you already know your string isn't null.  The more concerning issue is that methods like InStr use a one-base index instead of zero-base.  This doesn't play well with the .Net String functions that are zero-base.  Many developers also don't expect one-base results either.

Comment: Perhaps if `C$` had a meaningful name we (and/or maintainers of this code) could *glance* at it and know what it's *supposed* to be doing... oh right, it's extracting the *date* part of the string. If the format is fixed then you can greatly simplify this by just taking the 16 right-most characters...

Comment: Thank to everybody. I've a lot to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using Regex is the best way to extract the date from string, because you may use a different string every time, for example :

```
Dim stringDate = "something happens: 03/12/2014 11:00"
Dim stringDate = "something 03/12/2014 11:00"
Dim stringDate = "something happens:::>> 03/12/2014 11:00"
```

With the following code you can extract the date from all this strings :

```
Dim m As Match = New Regex("\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}").Match(stringDate)
If m.Success Then
    MsgBox(m.Value)
End If
```

But if you don't care about "Date" and just asking about `Right` and `Instr` then the `Substring` will be a nice solution and the way to use it is depends on your input string.

Comment: Is it possible to use regex (without if ... else) for distinguish between "Happy Xmas: 25/12/2014" and "Happy Xmas: 25/12/2014 10:04" so to extract date or Date and time? If "If...else" are necessary I think it will be more easy to use substring.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use "if .. else", you can check multiple date formats, just use the pipe `|` to separate the different patterns, for example : `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`, this pattern will extract the both formats "date" and "datetime".

Comment: It is great! Thanks. Only a last question: The obtained string is in format `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"` but I need it in format `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"` but `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")` doesn't seems to work ... any idea?

Comment: You are welcome,

Do you mean that the input string contains dates in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" format?

If so, you can replace `/` in the pattern with `-` or even you can replace it with `[./-]` and in this case you can extract date formats like : `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"` or `"yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm"` or `"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"`

But if you meant converting the `m.Value` from `"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"` format to `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"` then you can simply use `m.Value.Replace("/", "-")`

Comment: I mean converting "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" (for example 25/12/2014 12:30) to mySql style "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" (for example 2014-12-25 12:30)

Comment: `Dim dt As String = Convert.ToDateTime("25/12/2014 11:31").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77234/discussion-between-genespos-and-muhammad).